# Como agrupar por texto [R]

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Tenho uma coluna no dataset que possui várias variantes de 5 opções. Queria agrupar com base no que tem escrito em comum. Por exemplo:

```
coluna1 
lapis vermelho grande
lapis azul grande
lapis verde pequeno
lapis vermelho pequeno
```

**quero criar uma coluna, mantendo a original, mas agrupar por caracteristica**

```
    coluna1                  coluna2
lapis vermelho grande       caixa grande
lapis azul grande           caixa grande
lapis verde pequeno         caixa pequeno
lapis vermelho pequeno      caixa pequeno
```

pensei em criar um WHEN, ou if else
mas não consegui a logica pra capturar uma palavra na string..
alguém com sugestao?

Answer (score 3):

Com uma regex pode ser feito em uma linha de código.

```
df$coluna2 <- sub(".*\\b([^[:space:]]+$)", "\\1", df$coluna1)
```

Explicação da regex.

1. O grupo de captura `([^[:space:]]+$)` nega (`^`) a classe `space` e repete pelo menos uma vez. Este grupo vai até ao fim (`$`) da string.
2. O grupo de captura está precedido de uma fronteira de palavra, `\\b`.
3. Antes de `\\b` pode vir qualquer sequência de caracteres.

A string é substituida só pelo grupo capturado, `"\\1"`, que é sua a última palavra.

Comment: daora essa resolução, tem material de regex pra indicar?
valeu pela respsta

Comment: consigo aproveitar esse codigo e pegar palavras em posições diferentes? e o codigo conseguiria identificar uma palavra? por ex: coloco 'vermelho' e ele chama todos que tiverem vermelho independente da posição?

Comment: @whatshallwedon0w Não, esta expressão regular só encontra a última palavra. Para extrair uma palavra, por exemplo 'vermelho', pode fazer `stringr::str_extract(df$coluna1, 'vermelho')`.

Comment: @whatshallwedon0w Quanto a material de regex, veja [R base](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) ou pacote [stringr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Solução `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df %>% 
  mutate(.data = ., coluna2 = case_when(
  equals(e1 = ., e2 = 'lapis vermelho grande') ~ "caixa grande", 
  equals(e1 = ., e2 = 'lapis azul grande') ~ "caixa grande", 
  equals(e1 = ., e2 = 'lapis verde pequeno') ~ "caixa pequeno", 
  equals(e1 = ., e2 = 'lapis vermelho pequeno') ~ "caixa pequeno"))

#                 coluna1       coluna2
#1  lapis vermelho grande  caixa grande
#2      lapis azul grande  caixa grande
#3    lapis verde pequeno caixa pequeno
#4 lapis vermelho pequeno caixa pequeno
```